# Opening ArcSDE connection file ( .sde ) & checking syntax?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase

When I used Notepad++ to open ArcSDE connection file(.sde) **encoding ANSI**, it's just messy code!

Is there any application available to open it ?

Or anyone can give a sde file example **encoding utf-8** to me?

[image]

Comment: have you tried opening it up in normal notepad?

Comment: It is a binary file with encryption. You should not edit it, ***ever***.

Comment: @MapMan  Yes,but it's still messy code!   And I also saved it as file encoding utf-8,but it  just  turned parts of codes ,still messy codes!

Answer (score 1):

It's not a text file so changing encoding wouldn't change the thing. If you need to get some data from it you should work with it from ArcGIS environment, open properties tab for this connection and find what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Now I know more about what it is !Best wishes!